# call back inside callback in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have following nodejs code:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res){

    db.collection('com_url_mamy').find().toArray(function(err, doc){
      db.collection('com_url_mamy').find({'price':''}).count(function(err, docs){
        db.collection('com_url_mamy').find({"price":{$not:{$ne:"last_price_1"}}}).count(function(err, last_doc){

        if(err){console.log(err);}
        console.log(docs);
      res.render('dashboard',{'doc':doc, 'docs':docs, 'last_doc':last_doc});
    });
    });
  });
```

Here i have to add more two or three query/callback.

But I don't think this is right way to do.
Please any one can me tell me how I can solve this problem to increase performance.

Thank You

Comment: @MehdiElFadil This is not a duplicate. He can improves a lot his code using Promises and multiple concurrent async calls. The question you linked is about code style while his question is about performance issue in a particular scenario than can be improved.

Comment: I pasted my answer here since question has been closed for no reason http://paste.ofcode.org/zHmnq2u8qKzDx9ggnYHep9

Since your 3 queries are not dependent on each others, you can use ```Promise.all``` to execute the 3 of them in parallel.

Comment: BTW ```{"price":{$not:{$ne:"last_price_1"}}}``` can be refactored to ```{"price": "last_price_1"}``` (not not equal is equal :p)

Answer (score 4):

Using async/await will be an appropriate solution that avoids the callback hell for you in this case. Consider running your queries as follows:

```
app.get('/user/:name', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const docs = await db.collection('com_url_mamy').find().toArray()
        const count = await db.collection('com_url_mamy').find({'price':''}).count()
        const last_doc = await db.collection('com_url_mamy').find({"price": "last_price_1"}).count()

        res.render('dashboard', { docs, count, last_doc })
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err)
    }
}
```

---

As an alternative, you can use the **[async](https://github.com/caolan/async)** libary especially the **[`async.parallel()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel)** method when you need to run multiple tasks that do not depend on each other and when they all finish do something else.

Consider the following example:

```
app.get('/user/:name', function(req, res, next) {
    var locals = {};
    async.parallel([

        // Load all documents 
        function(callback) {
            db.collection('com_url_mamy').find().toArray(function(err, docs){
                if (err) return callback(err);
                locals.docs = docs;
                callback();
            });
        },

        // Get count of documents where price is empty 
        function(callback) {
            db.collection('com_url_mamy').find({'price':''}).count(function(err, count){
                if (err) return callback(err);
                locals.count = count;
                callback();
            });
        },

        // Load last docs 
        function(callback) {
            db.collection('com_url_mamy').find({"price": "last_price_1"}).count(function(err, docs){
                if (err) return callback(err);
                locals.last_doc = docs;
                callback();
            });
        }
    ], function(err) { //This function gets called after the three tasks have called their "task callbacks"
        if (err) return next(err);
        //Here render dashboard with locals object
        res.render('dashboard', locals);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use native Promises with MongoDB driver (on node.js >= 0.12):

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res){
  var proms = [];

  proms.push(db.collection('com_url_mamy').find().toArray());
  proms.push(db.collection('com_url_mamy').find({'price':''}).count());
  proms.push(db.collection('com_url_mamy').find({"price": "last_price_1"}).count());

  Promise.all(proms)
  .then(function(pres) {
    res.render('dashboard',{'doc':pres[0], 'docs': pres[1], 'last_doc': pres[2]});
  })
  .catch(console.error);
});
```

`Promise.all` takes the promises you give it and execute them in parallel.

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

(BTW I think you should rename your question with something more like 'Improve independent nested async calls' to avoid the closing/duplicate issue you had.)